# C linked list and nodes program, why am I getting a unhanded exception?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, nodes, unhandled-exception

How do I fix error I keep getting when I run the program? Im trying to make head point to the address of first and then be able to pass *first through a function where a new node will be created, the user can give it data at run-time, and then first will point to the new node! Am I doing this right?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void addToStart (struct node** head);
void Menu();
void DisplayList(struct node* head);

struct node{

    int data;
    struct node *next;

};


void main(){

    int option = 0;

    struct node *head;
    struct node *first;
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    first = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data= 0;
    head->next = first;
    first->data = 1;
    first->next = NULL;

    Menu();
    scanf(" %d", option);

    while(option != 6){
        switch(option){
        case 1:
            addToStart(&first);
            break;
        case 3:
            DisplayList(head);
        break;
    case 6:
        exit(0);
        break;

    default:
        printf("\nTry Again");
        break;
        }//switch end
    }//while end

}

void addToStart (struct node** first)
{
struct node *newNode;
newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
printf("\nEnter data for this node");
scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
newNode->next = *first;
*first = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
}

void Menu(){

    printf("1) Add a node.\n");
    printf("3) Display all nodes.\n");
    printf("6) Exit.\n");


}

void DisplayList(struct node* head){

    struct node *temp;
    temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;
    while( temp!= NULL )
    {
        printf("Data: %d", temp->data); // show the data
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: where and what error, please?

Comment: `temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;` This is probably unrelated to your error, but if you're setting `temp` to `head` then the first line is unnecessary and leads to a memory leak.

Comment: and `addToStart(&first);` --> `addToStart(&head);` ?,  `while(option != 6){` : never update `option`

Comment: What do you mean by "unhandled exception"? C++ has exceptions; C doesn't. Please update your question to show the exact error message you're getting. Also, if some instructor, book, or tutorial told you to use `void main()` find a better one; it's `int main(void)`. (Some compilers will accept `void main()`, but there's no good reason to use it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node{

    int data;
    struct node *next;

};

void addToStart (struct node** head);
void Menu();
void DisplayList(struct node* head);




int main(){

    int option = 0;

    struct node *head;
    //struct node *first;
    //head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //first = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head = NULL;

    option = 0;
    while(option != 6){
        Menu();
        scanf(" %d", &option);
        switch(option){

            case 1:
                addToStart(&head);
                                break;
            case 3:
                DisplayList(head);
                                break;
            case 6:
                exit(0);

                break;

            default:
                printf("\nTry Again");
                break;
        }//switch end
    }//while end

}

void addToStart (struct node** head)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\nEnter data for this node");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*head==NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *lastNode = *head;
        while(lastNode->next!=NULL)
            lastNode = lastNode->next;
        lastNode->next = newNode;


    }

   // *first = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
}

void Menu(){

    printf("\n1) Add a node.\n");
    printf("3) Display all nodes.\n");
    printf("6) Exit.\n");


}

void DisplayList(struct node* head){

    struct node *temp;
    temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;
    while( temp!= NULL )
    {
        printf("Data: %d", temp->data); // show the data
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

This works.

Many points you should consider:

1) it is `int main`, not `void main()`

2) give address of variable you want to set value for when you do `scanf`. it should be `scanf(" %d", &option);` not `scanf(" %d", option);`

3) When you made a new node, you were not setting its next to NULL. This was missing. `newNode->next = NULL;`

4) You were in infinite loop. `option` was never updated. I added that. Also, Menu should be shown after user has given his choice.

5) There is no check for memory allocation. What if `malloc` returns `NULL`?

6) You were getting confused with `first` and `head`. Convention is to use `head`.

7) I would use `typedef` , instead of `struct node` everytime. This is left as an exercise :)

OP, this list is not exhaustive.

If you want to display numbers in reverse order, change the else part in `addToStart` like this

```
else
    {
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }
```

Comment: 3) : `next` has been set.

Comment: your `addToStart` is `addToLast`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , yes . Did not realize it. I guess it is good in a way since it is clear OP is still learning the basics. I gave addToLast, OP should be able to figure out addToStart.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll try work with this and hopefully ill make some progress!

Comment: By the way how come we dont allocate new memory with malloc for head? I was thought this is how we declare a node using a struct to make sure theres memory at runtime?

Comment: @conortighe. , actually, head is pointing to an allocated memory location. When head is NULL, head points to memory allocated by newNode. I would suggest draw a diagram, dump the addresses of newNode and head and see. That way you will learn more. To dump - use &head and &newNode.

Comment: @conortighe., Please accept this answer if it helped you. I see you are new to StackOverflow so it is understandable if someone shows you the rope here. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dump? pass through functions as &head?

Comment: @conortighe., Sorry to have used lingo, I should have used print. Here is what I meant. printf("%u,%u",&head,&newNode); do this in addToStart function, just before it is exiting. &<variable name> gives the address as you already know. You will see how head and NewNode point to same address location initially. Head is just a pointer to a memory location. So is newNode. Allocating just one is enough.

Comment: @conortighe., if things are not clear even after that, do not hesitate to ask questions. I can see you want to learn, which is always a good thing. :)

Comment: Thanks! by the way is %u giving you the address its pointing at?

Comment: @Anon: No, don't use `%u` to print addresses. `%u` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. `%p` takes a `void*` pointer. To print an address value: `printf("%p, %p\n", (void*)&head, (void*)&newNode)`

Comment: @conortighe., You get the address because of "&" in front of the variables. %u, %d, %f, %p are format specifiers. U is for unsigned integers, F for float etc. So there is nothing like printing with %u gives address. You could use printf("%p, %p\n", (void*)&head,(void*)&newNode) and it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node{

    int data;
    struct node *next;

};

void addToStart (struct node** head);
void addToEnd (struct node** head);
void Menu();
void Size(struct node* head);
void DisplayList(struct node* head);
void SearchList(struct node* head);



int main(){

    int option = 0;

    struct node *head;
    struct node *first;
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    first = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head = NULL;

    option = 0;
    while(option != 6){
        Menu();
        scanf(" %d", &option);
        switch(option){

            case 1:
                addToStart(&head);
                                break;
            case 2:
                addToEnd(&head);
                break;
            case 3:
                DisplayList(head);
                                break;
            case 4:
                Size(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                SearchList(head);
                break;
            case 6:
                free(head);
                free(first);
                exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nTry Again");
                break;
        }//switch end
    }//while end

}

void addToStart (struct node** head)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\nEnter data for this node:\n");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*head==NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
         newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;

    }
    printf("%u,%u",&head,&newNode);
   // *first = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
}

void addToEnd (struct node** head)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\nEnter data for this node:\n");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*head==NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
         struct node *lastNode = *head;
         while(lastNode->next != NULL){
                lastNode = lastNode->next;
             lastNode->next = newNode;
         }

        *head = newNode;

    }

  // *first = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
}

void Size(struct node* head)
    {
        int len = 0;

        struct node *temp;
        temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL)
        {
           len++;
           temp = temp->next;

        }
      printf("Size of list:  %d", len);
    }


void Menu(){

    printf("\n1) Add a node.\n");
    printf("2) Add node to end.\n");
    printf("3) Display all nodes.\n");
    printf("4) Display the length of list.\n");
    printf("5) Search the list.\n");
    printf("6) Exit.\n");


}

void DisplayList(struct node* head){

    struct node *temp;
    temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;
    while( temp!= NULL )
    {
        printf("Data: %d  ", temp->data); // show the data
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}



void SearchList(struct node* head){

    int keynum;
    struct node *temp;
    temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;

    printf("\nEnter number:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &keynum);

    if(temp->data  == keynum){
        printf("\n%d was found in the list!\n", keynum);
    }
    else{
        printf("\n%d is not in the list!\n", keynum);

    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, this looks neat and tidy :). I see you added new methods by yourself.